# Getting text-overflow: ellipsis to work with required content after

Tags: css

I have a list with text and counts, like so:

```
+----------------------------+
| Some text (123)            |
| Some other text (456,789)  |
+----------------------------+
```

In my UI, I'm constrained on space, so I want to make sure the count fits in the allotted space. To make this happen, I've used `text-overflow: ellipsis;` on my text, so ideally I'd see this:

```
+--------------------+
| Some text (123)    |
| Some ot… (456,789) |
+--------------------+
```

But my count isn't winning. It's being pushed out of the box, like so:

```
+--------------------+
| Some text (123)    |
| Some other t… (456,789)
+--------------------+
```

As you can see, the ellipsis logic is still firing, but... just not well. :-)

[Here's a handy-dandy JSFiddle demonstrating the issue.](http://jsfiddle.net/inanutshellus/h4LEM/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about flex-grow/flex-shrink?

```
.parent-div {
    display: -moz-flex;
    display: flex;
    border: 1px solid lightblue;
    max-width:500px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.text {
    white-space: nowrap;
    min-width: 1px; 
    border: 2px dotted lightgreen;
    overflow: hidden;
    flex-grow: 0;
    flex-shrink: 1;
}

.icon {
    display: -moz-flex-inline-block;
    display: flex-inline-block;
    border: 2px dotted pink;
    white-space: nowrap;
    flex-grow: 1;
    flex-shrink: 0;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/h4LEM/7/

Answer (score 1):

Input the `count` first and `float` that to the `right` - http://jsfiddle.net/h4LEM/11/

Possible issue that count is then aligned to the right.